# Unable to insert multiple checkbox data in the database

Tags: php, codeigniter

UPDATED. I'm having problem about inserting multiple checkbox data in the database.

Here is my view

```
 <?php 
            $i = 0;
            $qArr = array();
            $qArrc = 0;
            $qArr1 = array();
            $qArrc1 = 0;
            $uArr = array();
            $u = 0;
            foreach($questions->result() as $q){ ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="check[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $qArr[$qArrc++] = $q -> questions; ?>"> <?php echo $q->questions; ?> <br>
                <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $uArr[$u++] = $this->session->userdata('user_id'); ?>" name="hidden[<?php echo $i; ?>]" type="hidden">
                <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $qArr1[$qArrc1] = $q->id; ?>" name="hidden1[<?php echo $i; ?>]" type="hidden">
            <?php 
            $i++;                               
            }?>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Here's my controller

```
                for($i = 0; $i<count($this->input->post('check')); $i++){
                $data1 = array(  
                    'question' => $this->input->post('check')[$i],
                    'speaker_id' => $this->input->post('hidden')[$i],
                    'question_id' => $this->input->post('hidden1')[$i]
                );  
                $this->input->post('submit');  

                     $this->Speaker_Model->insert_speakerfeedback($data1);  


            }redirect('speaker/createfeedback');
```

Here's my model

```
      public function insert_speakerfeedback($data1){
        $this->db->insert("speakerdata", $data1);
    }
```

Comment: You do `redirect` after first insert, what do you expect?

Comment: __After__ `for` loop.

Comment: Ow. Yes you're right. Thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `for` loops :

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($this->input->post('check')); $i++){
```

to use `foreach` instead` :

```
foreach ($this->input->post('check') as $i => $value) {
```

So it will prevent getting undefined index if you skip some checkbox. And the redirect line should be outside of the loops.

For bulk insert, you could use `insert_batch` function.

Within the loop, change :

```
$data1 = array(
```

to

```
$data1[] = array(
```

So it will not overwriting on each iteration.

And on the Model, change :

```
$this->db->insert("speakerdata", $data1);
```

to :

```
$this->db->insert_batch("speakerdata", $data1);
```

Comment: Hi I already update the question, the only problem now is how to insert multiple checkbox datas. But thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Well this suggestion is helpful too!!